# Numerical Methods: Float Aritmetic Sum

Tags: numerical-methods

I am in a course of numerical methods and I have a question:

If I have the harmonic sum:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{i}$ and I can approximate it by "rounding" it. This rounding can be defined as:

$S_n = fl(S_{n-1} +a_n)$ where the $a_n$ are the harmonic terms. My question is if there is way to know when the sum $S_n$ will stop growing and be constant, for $n$ big enough. I mean, given a certain presition $m$ of digits to approximate, how can I know the $n$ that will "stop" the sum.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio:  You are correct in the reals.  In computer floating point there is such a number.

Comment: @RossMillikan: ok, I probably misunderstood the question. So the point is to provide asymptotics for $H_n$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio:  just to find the $n$ so that $\frac 1n$ is so small compared to $H_n$ that it does not change the sum in floating point.  Floating point has a resolution based on the number of bits assigned to the mantissa.  For my old 32 bit  single precision machines it was about $2^{-23}$, so if $\frac 1n  \lt 2^{-23} \log n$ it will not change the sum,

Answer (score 1):

Your sum is $H_n$,the $n^{\rm {th}}$ [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).  We have $H_n \approx \log n + \gamma$, where $\gamma \approx 0.577$  You are being asked to estimate the $n$ where $\frac 1n \lt H_n \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is the smallest number that can be added to $1$ which gives a different result.

Comment: So asymptotically the question is about when $n \log(n) > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$. To leading order this occurs when $n>-\frac{1}{\epsilon \log(\epsilon)}$. In double precision this will be somewhere between $n=10^{14}$ and $n=10^{15}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to solve
$$n \log(n) =\frac{1}{\epsilon}$$ the solution is given in terms of Lambert function
$$n=\frac{\frac 1\epsilon}{  W\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon }\right)}$$ which can be approximated by
$$n\sim\frac{\frac 1\epsilon}{\log\left(\frac 1\epsilon \right)-\log \left(\log \left(\frac{1}{\epsilon }\right)\right)}$$

For $\epsilon=2^{-23}$, the approximation would give $n=636784$ while the exact solution would be $n=628322$.